# Binding events to not yet created DOM elements (jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, dom

How do I bind events to html elements that don't exist at the time of the script loading?

One part of my script adds these to the DOM:

```
<a class="btn-remove-item" href="">link</a>
```

The problem is I can't just do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".btn-remove-item").click(function(){
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    });
});
```

.. I think because the DOM element isn't there when the page first loads.

How should I bind the event to myClass?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated. Here is the accepted answer using [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-remove-item', function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, thanks to this, I can bind events on my Angular generated elements

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery [live() function](http://api.jquery.com/live/) does this:

```
$("#btn-remove-item").live('click', function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
});
```

Comment: live is deprecated, how can I achieve it through `on`?

Comment: you can use 'on', just select via `document` and use the selector argument of 'on' to get the right element.  e.g. `$(document).on( 'click', '#someThingCreatedLater', function (event) { ... do stuff ...});`

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is what you need.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.myClass").live('click', function() {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    });
});
```

**Try it out**: http://jsfiddle.net/mwR8g/

Comment: `live()` is deprecated now. Use `on()`. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8191450/1738090

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".btn-remove-item").live('click', function() {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    });
});
```

You are need to use live.