# How do I bind a click event to an object that is not yet in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, dom, coffeescript

First of all, I tried the answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392024/binding-events-to-not-yet-created-dom-elements-jquery),  [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084293/how-to-make-live-click-event-on-new-added-dom) similar questions,  but that does not seem to work for me at all.

I would like to do stuff on a click event bound to an element that is created via ajax so it is not in the DOM at first.

I notice that the following coffeescript in `my_asset.js.coffee` works as expected:

```
$ ->  
  $('#div').on "click", ".link", (e) -> 
    #do stuff
```

According to JQuery Doc:
*this function is bound to all "selected_div" click events, even if they are added to the DOM via ajax later*
And the `do stuff` part works ok

However I would like to:

```
$(this).after("<%= insert some long view here %>")
```

So, in order to do that, I guess I should move the `$(this).after` part from the `asset.js.coffee` to `my_view.js.erb`
where I could embed `render partial`

There, in `my_view.js.erb`, I have tried the following, (equivalent) javascript:

```
$(function() {  
  $("#div").on("click", ".link", function() {
    $(this).after("<%= render partial here %>");
  });
});
```

But it does not work for the first click, (it does, however, for the subsequent clicks)

I think it is related to the fact that `.link` is not in the DOM when the page loads for the first time.

Why is this happening? Is that the cause? And how could I get in the view the same behaviour that I get in the asset ?

Comment: Is #div in the DOM on page load? Try using: $("body").on("click", "#div .link", function() {

Comment: Yes, it Is. Tried that, but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

You'll bind to a container element (typically `document` or `body`), and [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) the event to the to-be-created object:

```
$(document).on("click", "#div .link", function() {
    $(this).after("<%= insert some long view here %>");
});
```

---

**Binding**

As you've pointed out, JS binds events to elements of the DOM on page load

If your element is not present at load, `JS` won't be able to bind, thus causing a problem. To fix this, you'll have to delegate the bind to an element *higher* in the `DOM` hierarchy, allowing JS to bind the event to any new elements in relation to your container

Comment: Well I have tried this, but it does not work for me. I'd like to make it clear that, in  what I tried: `$("#div").on("click", ".link", function() { ` #div IS in the DOM on page load. I have also tried with `$(document).on("click", "#div .link", function() {` but still , I can't get what I want. Works from second click, but not for first

Comment: Can I use the same function (same on click on same link) in `my_asset.js.coffee` and in `my_view.js.erb` ? Why does it work in the asset and not in the view?  And what order are they executed?

Comment: Can you post your HTML for `#div` and `.link`?

Comment: Sure, this is the html for .link: `<a class="sii_link" data-remote="true" data-sii-id="24337" format="js" href="/spectrum_identifications/8/results/24334/identification_item?sii_id=24337">SII_1_1_Mzid_2</a>` and tthe #div is a table (the links are created in it later, but it exists on page load ) : `<table class="my_table" id="sii_table"> `